# SQL STR() function equality

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2005

Why this sql statement returns no row in SQL 2005?

```
select 1 from tblMessage where '210' = STR(210)
```

This should be always true and returns all rows in the table.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default length returned by [STR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) is 10. You could specify a length.

```
select 1 from tblMessage where '210' = STR(210,3)
```

Comment: Nice answer, @JoeStefanelli.  I tried it and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

`STR` creates a string of [length 10 by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

Try:

```
select ltrim(str(210))
```

Or, you can specify the string length if you know how long your number is, e.g.:

```
select str(210, 3)
```

You could also use the number itself to determine the length, e.g.:

```
select str(210, len(210))
```

So, a working example:

```
declare @n as int
set @n = 123
select case when str(@n, len(@n)) = '123' then 'equal' else 'not equal' end
```