# SQL JOIN WHERE IN STRING OF OTHER TABLE

Tags: sql, join

I need to join two tables together where the seccond table has one of the first tables in a string.

e.g

```
Table1 has ID1, ID2, Lang_id, User, Text.

Table2 has ID_a, User, List_ID2.
```

Additionally, the `List_ID2` is comma seperated, so I have to make sure I get it in all cases, so if it is the only number, or the at beginning, middle or end of the string. BUT NOT truncate the values, i.e. (10 is not 100 - '10'0)

The extra kicker is that `Lang_id` is the language of the `Place` and I also have to seperate that.

I have the language seperated fine, I can't get the `ID_a` into my results

i.e

```
TABLE 1
ID1 ID2 Lang_id User    Text
1   2   1   bob Me
1   2   2   bob Mich
1   2   3   bob Mi
2   1   1   bob You
2   1   2   bob Du
2   1   3   bob usted
3   1   1   tim You
3   1   2   tim Dich
3   1   3   tim le
4   3   1   tim Hello
4   3   2   tim Hallo
4   3   3   tim ihola

TABLE 2
ID_a    User    List_ID2
100 bob 1, 2
200 tim 1, 3

RESULTS
ID_a    ID1 ID2 English German  Spanish
100 1   1   You Du  usted
100 2   2   Me  Mich    Mi
200 3   1   You Dich    le
200 4   3   Hello   Hallo   ihola
```

My statement looks a little like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT main.ID1, main.ID2, ID_a
  (SELECT Text
   FROM table1 AS a
   WHERE lang_id = 1
     AND main.ID1 = a.ID1
     AND main.ID2 = a.ID2) AS English,
  (SELECT Text
   FROM table1 AS b
   WHERE lang_id = 2
     AND main.ID1 = b.ID1
     AND main.ID2 = b.ID2) AS German,
  (SELECT Text
   FROM table1 AS c
   WHERE lang_id = 3
     AND main.ID1 = c.ID1
     AND main.ID2 = c.ID2) AS Spanish,
FROM table1 AS main
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table2.User = main.User
AND (table2.List_ID2 LIKE STR(ID2)
OR table2.List_ID2 LIKE (ID2 + ',%')
OR table2.List_ID2 LIKE ('%,' + ID2 + ',%')
OR table2.List_ID2 LIKE ('%,' + ID2)
```

The first part is working fine (the language is seperated), but I can't get the ID from table2, I've tried a few differnt methods, and the above comes back without an error, but alot of NULL values.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure what versions at the moment, but we are using SQL Server, with sybase (SQL Anywhere12), and I don't know the name of the 'command promt' tool, but I believe it is part of Sybase. We have an ERP (Enterprise Resource planning) tool, written in C++. The script will executed from the ERP using an ODBC connect (directly in the code)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here:
[SQL STR() function equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609822/sql-str-function-equality)

I needed to specify the Length of the STR()